# Probability using counting method

Tags: probability

You have a bag of 50 Jelly Bellies, one bean for each of the 50 Jelly Belly Flavours, including Cherry Passion Fruit, Mandarin Orange Mango, Strawberry Banana and Pineapple Pear

a) If you reach in and grab 4 Jelly Bellies, what are the odds in favour of you ending up with 1 Cherry Passion Fruit, 1 Mandarin Orange Mango, 1 Strawberry Banana and 1 Pineapple Pear?

b) If you reach in and take one Jelly Belly at a time, what are the odds in favour of you eating first a Mixed Berry, then a Pineapple Pear, then a Mandarin Orange Mango, and finally a Cherry Passion Fruit?

Comment: This seems rather homework-problem-ish. But to get you started: how many ways are there of ordering all 50 of jelly beans? Of those orderings, how many are there to rearrange them so that the first four are the required flavors?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. On this platform, you are required to first show what you have attempted and where you are stuck before appropriate help can be given.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community : "As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking" : no it isn't.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm totally off the mark here so take this with a grain of salt.

The possible number of outcomes for choosing 4 jelly beans out of  50 $\binom{50}{4}$. There's only one possible four subset for getting cherry Passion Fruit, 1 Mandarin Orange Mango, 1 Strawberry Banana and 1 Pineapple Pear.

$$\frac{1}{\binom{50}{4}}$$

For the second question, the total number of ways to order the jellybeans (It doesn't say anything about placing the beans back so non-replacement) is 50!. If we assume that the first four jellybeans are already placed then we have 46 more to order.

$$\frac{46!}{50!}$$

Comment: Please do not answer questions that do not meet [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).